# How to create external source maps so can use the Chrome debugger in Vscode / Typescript for the browser using Gulp

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, gulp, visual-studio-code

I wish to use Gulp to build my very simple Typescript project *running in the browser*. Using `gulp-typescript` it appears to add modules.export into the generated js files, so I then found some `browserify` examples.

I now have the following gulp.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var browserify = require("browserify");
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify = require("tsify");

gulp.task('clean', function () {
   return del(['build/**/*']);
});

 gulp.task("copy-html", function () {
   return gulp.src("*.html")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
gulp.task("copy-css", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/*.css")
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
gulp.task("default", ["clean", "copy-html", "copy-css"], function () {
  return browserify({
    basedir: '.',
    debug: true,
    entries: ['src/main.ts'],
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {}
 })
.plugin(tsify)    
.bundle()    
.pipe(source('bundle.js'))        
.pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

This creates bundle.js, and this seems to have the soucemaps embedded in it. Debugging on Chrome seems to work fine, but I am trying to use the vscode Chrome debugger plugin from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug), but breakpoints are disabled.

My launch.json is as follows.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
  "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "file": "${workspaceRoot}/build/index.html",
  "sourceMaps": true

},
{
  "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "attach",
  "port": 9222,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
  }
 ]
}
```

So I thought perhaps I need the external source maps, so have tried using the `gulp-sourcemaps` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps), but just can't get the example to work with the above script (no matter where I insert the `.pipe(sourcemaps.init())` and `.pipe(sourcemaps.write())` I get gulp build errors.

I have tried various suggestions, but none work (perhaps many of them are now out of date, e.g. using `outDir` in launch.json I get the error `Property ourDir is not allowed.`

So, am just after whatever I need to do to use this debugger with, Typescript, in Chrome, which to me I thought would be common, but cannot find an example to get this working. I am guessing it is the (embedded) sourcemaps, but not sure.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does your "Launch Chrome" actually start up chrome and find your localhost?  I don't see a url option there.  I started with that same example code you linked to and it didn't work for me as is, I added some options I found elsewhere and it works.  Here's my "launch"

```
    {
        "name": "Chrome : Launch with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
       // "preLaunchTask": "sync",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "runtimeArgs": [
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ]
    }
```

Note the localhost port, which is what my browserSync is using (and browserSync is started **first**, in my case with a preLaunchTask or manually with a gulp task call).  I am not using browserify or typescript so I don't know much about them so I apologize if this code doesn't make sense with them.  But I would try adding the url option with your port number and the runtimeArgs option and see if they help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried the above and only got a "This site can’t be reached" after Chrome launched. I am not using the browserSync though. Using my options as above, Chrome does launch and open the page, with `file:///H:/dev/myprojl/build/index.html` in the address bar. All appears to work except to break points, where the tooltip says `Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?).` Tried combinations of the above flags, just cannot get it to work at all.

Comment: Are you setting your breakpoints in the build/bundle.js file?  Secondly, are you using the launch or attach option?  I assume for the attach option to work chrome must already be open - preferably a single tab I have read - to your site with the debugger port enabled when you start that instance of chrome.

Comment: I was trying to use the launch option, but if I need to attached that would be fine too. I am setting the break points in the `.ts` files, that is where I would want to debug (just like I can in the browser debugger).

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md  a gulp recipe for using browserify - it looks like you might have to do some special things to get sourcemaps working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and setting the `sourceRoot` in the build task fixed it for me. Howere I didn't use browserify...

But try to add gulp-sourcemaps to the pipe:

```
gulp.task("default", ["clean", "copy-html", "copy-css"], function () {
  return browserify({
    basedir: '.',
    debug: true,
    entries: ['src/main.ts'],
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {}
 })
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.plugin(tsify)    
.bundle()    
.pipe(source('bundle.js'))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '/src'}))        
.pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```